# SVG Export change some square into circle - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, cc-2018

I have a weird issue with an svg export with some vectorised image.
When i make on svg export, some square are change to circle and i have no clue why.

You can download the .ai here (made on cc 2018)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/22oeivmvbg60yki/Sushi2.ai?dl=0

What i have:
[image]

Export Setting:

[image]

What i get:

[image]

I have the same issue with some other image.

Comment: Hi Cyril Vellas, welcome to GD.SE. The best and I think unique way to help you is seeing the svg you are trying to export. You should include it in the question. And the tag of the program you use as well.

Comment: I've add the link for the .ai !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exported two squares, one that appears as a circle and the other normal, and this is the result:

```
<g id="Calque_1" data-name="Calque 1">
<circle class="cls-1" cx="205.94" cy="205.94" r="291.24"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M411.88,411.88V0H823.75V411.88Z"/>
</g>
```

I don't know how you did the illustration, it looks like something traced, but as you can see there is a circle and a normal path.

The only solution I can see is to select all the circle paths and go to menu **Effect** > **Convert to Shape** > **Rectangle** > Relative, EW=0, EH=0.

[image: Convert to shape]

I did that in some of the circles on the left:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked !

For this, i have a .png file and i convert to vector with the "Image Trace" tool.
Don't know really what does the fact that some shape are considered as Circle but yhea, just gonna onvert in rectangle. 

Thanks !

Comment: @CyrilVellas you should probably use the  Object Mosaic instead of tracing.

Comment: @joojaa Gonna try that next time, i'm not used of Illustrator. Thanks anyway !